# Windows driver APIs not written by Microsoft

Tags: windows, audio, driver

I've been on a little adventure learning about how Windows platforms deal with sounds. Now I know a couple of things from taking an Operating System class and reading [this](http://www.staudio.de/kb/english/drivers/):

- IO devices such as a sound card communicate with the OS through a device driver. Microsoft supplies a standard so that in kernel mode the OS can make certain system calls (in this case Win32 api calls) to make an I/O device do something. Bytes or characters are streamed to over buses to whatever port the I/O device resides in. These are interpreted by the device controller as instructions for the physical hardware.
- There are OS calls to prepare audio devices and stream data to them. Actually for some reason their are 2 ways to do this: MMSystem and DirectSound. I think the reason there are 2 has something to do with gaming? Like DIrectSound was more geared toward that while MMsystem was more standard apps that need audio?
- Beyond that their are also other audio APIs NOT written by microsoft for the Win32 platform. ASIO and GSIF.

How can these non Microsoft standards exist on the Windows platform? How can they possibly communicate with hardware or the OS? With something like openGL(something else I toy with), a version of Windows supports a version openGL standard and so does you GPU. BAM, easy-peasy no problems, everything checks out.
How I see it can be is:

1. MMsystem and/or DirectSound are not part of Win32, but there is some even lower level windows kernel driver everyone is keeping a secret because it's really ugly or
2. These other driver API's are built on top of the Microsoft supplied ones

Can someone please clarify? Where am I mistaken, I am missing something. I own my old OS textbook still(Modern Operating Systems 3rd Ed. by Tanenbaum) so if you want to point at something in there, go for it.

Comment: Windows allows different levels of drivers. Some drivers (high-level) make use of the hardware through lower-level drivers which may be provided by Windows. However, you can write a driver which interact directly with the hardware: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564864(v=vs.85).aspx